# Why will the National League not adopt the DH?

Tags: mlb

In the AL, the DH position allows older hitters to preserve their career for several more years. Why will the National League not adopt the DH given this benefit?

Comment: Many would argue that the DH detracts from the game. The baseball traditionalists or purists would have a fit if the NL adopted the DH.

Comment: As diggers3's reply hints at, I suspect this question is likely to generate more heat than light. As such, I'm voting to close as "opinion based". If you can refine the question to focus on something which is going to have a fact-based answer, I'll retract that vote.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think it's a good question. A question that would be too opinion-based would be "Should the NL adopt the DH?" However, this doesn't ask that. Instead, it asks what the reasons are for not adopting the DH, which is on topic and answerable.

Comment: @BenMiller Other than "Why will the National League not adopt the DH?", the rest of the question doesn't provide context outside of watching older players play for several more years and is merely [ranting](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. I have revised your question to eliminate any potential ranting to clearly focus on the question at hand based on what you had provided.

Answer (score 3):

There are compelling reasons to introduce the DH to the National League and compelling reasons to remove the DH from the American League. Most likely the answer to your question comes down to money.

By introducing the DH to the National League, there would be 15 more starting positions across MLB. The prototypical DH is a power hitter. These types of players usually command expensive contracts. NL team owners don't want to introduce the DH so they can avoid paying those contracts. AL team owners likely have a reason to keep the DH out of NL as well. If the NL were to introduce the DH, there would be increased demand for those types of players, inflating DH salaries.

The question points out that the DH can extend the careers of players. Old players make more money than young players, because they can become free agents.

Keep in mind that the DH was instituted in the AL to increase offense as a way to bolster attendance, and consequently revenues. Although offense is at a low point in today's game, right now, MLB is flush with money from TV deals, so that pressure does not exist.